# How do I create an instance of OnClickListener

Tags: android

I wrote  this code, but I get an error with View.OnClickListener.

The error said that View can't be resolve as type. I have imported android.view.View.OnClickListener but still get the same error.

If I use the quick fix another error appears.

```
public class Net extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{  
    EditText edt;
    TextView text;
    Button ping;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        ping=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ping);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
    }

     public void onClick(View v)
     {
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ping.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: tq. I have been try it. now the error appear at Button.setOnClickListener ,view v and implements View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

First Create class of the On click listener.

```
class InvestorOnclickListness implements View.OnClickListener{

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch(view.getId())
                {
                case R.id.buttonhome:
                {
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                        default:
                    break;
                      }
```

Then Create the Object of this class Inside the Oncreate or Onstart method and set the object with the button.

```
InvestorOnclickListness investorOnclickListness = new InvestorOnclickListness();
buttonhome.setOnClickListener(investorOnclickListness);
```

Hope this help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have import problem. Just look at to your import library file, does it contain following library ?

```
import android.view.View;
```

if not then put this line to your import list.

Comment: i cant see it properly, just put it in your question by editing it. so everyone else can see it too

Comment: becase i couldnt see here properly. if you add it in your question then it would be better to catch the mistake or error

Comment: android - i've post the coding in the new page.

Comment: how i want to fix OnClickListener1   - the title

Comment: page 4.   title:  how do i want to fix OnClickListener1

Comment: do you find question title how do i want to fix OnClickListener1? that is my question too

Comment: yes, another question. because i can't paste my full code here.  pls help me. sorry for troubling you

Comment: then  you can edit this question detail and paste it there... you dont need to ask new question.

Comment: i'm new here. so didn't really know about this stackoverflow.

Comment: that's ok , just give me the link of that question please

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the line

Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());

and the error is
Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

there are two solutions i will suggest

1: register the onclickListener  like this

```
                  saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
             // your code , what you want to execute when button is clicked
        }
    });
```

2: in xml file include onClick property with button

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberBTN"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:onClick="functioname without paranthesis You want to execute when button is clicked "
```

and then define the function in your  activity
            public void functinName(View V)
            {
              // your code
            }
        />

Comment: the android:onClick i have to type it. it will change the color or not?  i'm sorry because troubling you guys.. i'm don't know what to do now.i'm stuck